# What happened to my table in my oracle database?

Tags: oracle, computer-forensics

I have a situation where yesterday my code was working ok, but today I find that my code fails because a SQL query fails on my Oracle database.  The query fails because the table used in the query does not exists.  I am no Oracle expert so I am reaching out to you Oracle experts out there.  Is there a way to see in a log file or log table when my table disappeared and who dropped my table?

Thanks

Comment: Is it not just as likely that the user that runs the query no longer has permissions to see that table?

Comment: @kevinsky yes that is also possible.  Do you know if there is a way for me to find out what changed?

Comment: If you are connecting as the table owner, and it really has gone, you could see if it's in the recycle bin, and if so you can get the time it as dropped from `user_recyclebin`. If you are connecting as someone else perhaps someone rebuilt the table and forgot to re-grant permissions, or recreate a synonym. Hopefully this is a dev environment and you aren't seeing uncontrolled changes somewhere more important...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on previous configuration one would hope that a production database would have auditing turned on.  Try

```
select * from sys.AUD$
```

The audit table can log almost every user action  including dropping tables or revoking grants but has to be configured.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the recyclebin turned on in your database, you might be able to restore the dropped table. As the user who owns the table, you can run this query:

```
select * from USER_RECYCLEBIN
```

or if you have SYS access you can check the query:

```
SELECT * from DBA_RECYCLEBIN;
```

Then as a user owns the table, run this [`FLASHBACK` command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adfns/flashback.html#GUID-03D1CAAE-D940-444A-8771-B1BC636D105D) to restore it:

```
FLASHBACK TABLE <your table name> TO BEFORE DROP;
```

If you get ORA-38305 you might have a tablespace issue - either run it as a different user or make sure it using a locally managed tablespace.